# UPDATING Table Column with new Entry

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am working on Oracle APEX. I want my report to show me the updated **Debit** value in **Total amount** column.The Report Query is shown in the following diagram mentioned below.

```
TABLE  "VENDOR_ACCOUNT" 
(  "VEN_ACCOUNTID"      NVARCHAR2(10), 
   "VEN_REGNO"          NVARCHAR2(10), 
   "VEN_TXDATE"         DATE, 
   "VEN_INVOICE_REFNO"  NVARCHAR2(10), 
   "TOTALAMOUNT"        NVARCHAR2(10), 
   "IN"                 NUMBER(10,0), 
   "OUT"                NUMBER(10,0) 
) 

SELECT "VEN_ACCOUNTID" , 
       "VEN_REGNO" , 
       "VEN_TXDATE" , 
       "VEN_INVOICE_REFNO" , 
       "TOTALAMOUNT" , 
       "IN",
       "OUT",   
       "TOTALAMOUNT"+"IN" as "CREDIT",
       "TOTALAMOUNT"-"OUT" as "DEBIT"
FROM Vendor_Account;
```

Required Scenario: I want to update the `TotalAmount` Column with `Debit` and `Credit`. The new `Debit` or `Credit` value has to be shown in the `TotalBalance` column on the next record.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Oracle analyitic function `LAG`:

```
Select "VEN_ACCOUNTID" , 
        "VEN_REGNO" , 
        "VEN_TXDATE" , 
        "VEN_INVOICE_REFNO" , 
        "TOTALAMOUNT" , 
        "TOTALAMOUNT" + lag("IN",1) over (ORDER BY "VEN_ACCOUNTID")
                      - lag("OUT",1) over (ORDER BY "VEN_ACCOUNTID") AS "NEW_TOTALAMOUNT",
        "IN",
        "OUT",  
        "TOTALAMOUNT"+"IN" as "CREDIT",
        "TOTALAMOUNT"-"OUT" as "DEBIT"
FROM    Vendor_Account;
```

Comment: @alen.. It is still giving me the same answer as i mentioned it in the diagram above.. no changes are being made !

Comment: Use the LAG function. Play around with it and see what it does. As I wrote the query, you should get a new column "new total" in the APEX report.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman what exactly is not working then? When i take your resultset from your question and run Alen's or Florin's query on it, it gives me what you ask for: totalamount + in of previous record - out of previous record. So is it your report that "does not work" or is the query incomplete? If it is, then your question did not provide enough detail.

Comment: Is the problem that you're expecting the table to be updated afterwards?  If so Alens query alone will not do this - it will simply return the values required per run.  You'd need to modify the query (combine it with an update for example) to make the changes stick

Comment: @Tom .. Here is the problem "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected". I tried to play around this query but still not works..and you can easily understand the problem.. it is well explained with diagrams. I want to Update the TOTAL AMOUNT Column should be updated in next entry if some changes are being made in DEBIT or CREDIT Column. Thankyou

Answer (score 5):

```
Select
    "VEN_ACCOUNTID" , 
    "VEN_REGNO" , 
    "VEN_TXDATE" , 
    "VEN_INVOICE_REFNO" , 
    "TOTALAMOUNT" AS "OLD_TOTALAMOUNT"
    "TOTALAMOUNT" + nvl(lag (nvl("IN",0)-nvl("OUT",0)) 
                             over (partition by "VEN_REGNO" order by "VEN_ACCOUNTID" 
                             )
                        ,0) AS "TOTALAMOUNT"
    "IN",
    "OUT",  
 from Vendor_Account;
```